# Как вытащить отдельный item из стиля темы?

Tags: android, android-style

У меня есть белая тема в приложении, и я сегодня попытался сделать вторую тему, темную. Вроде все получилось, но есть небольшая проблема - в item recyclerView в нужно установить цвет текста в textView нужно устанавливать в зависимости от выбранной темы. Я так понял что нужно добавить отдельный item в в главный стиль темы, но после того как я его добавил, я не могу получить к нему доступ из разметки. Вот как у меня установлен цвет в виджете сейчас:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tv_from"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="90dp"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textColor="#000" />
```

как видно из разметки - цвет черный, и он ставится независимо от темы, а у меня есть стили темы:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#5c626d</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#5c626d</item>
</style>
```

и вот стиль темной темы:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/darkColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/darkColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/darkColorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/darkColorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">#FFF</item>
</style>
```

я пробую поменять что-то и у меня приложение крашится с ошибкой связанной с ссылками. Я не могу понять как правильно поступить в данной ситуации, просто я только начал разбираться с темами и не все понимаю. Заранее спасибо за ценные советы и помощь.

### UPDATE

поменял в стилях с NoActionBar на DarkActionBar как показано выше - появляется такая ошибка:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.developer_4.test_login/com.example.developer_4.test_login.Screens.MainCenter}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

Comment: пока единственным решением было удалить строку в разметке

Comment: Как менял и какие ошибки? Гипотетически виджет должен использовать стили из своих атрибутов если они заданы, иначе из темы. То есть должно быть достаточно убрать `android:textColor="#000"` у `TextView` в разметке.

Comment: @woesss, я убрал в разметке эту строку, когда я меняю стили то у меня ошибка связанная с линками какими-то, я так и не понял в чем именно проблема, но почему-то когда меняю стиль, то приложение падает

Comment: Повторяю ещё раз: **Как менял и какие ошибки?** Логи показывайте. Как-то смущает, что в одной теме есть `DarkActionBar`, а в другой его нет вообще (`NoActionBar`)

Comment: @woesss. обновил вопрос, с ошибкой после изменения экшн бара, пришлось вернуть все обратно

Comment: В ошибке предлагается наоборот убрать экшн-бар. Можно наследовать тему без него или убрать атрибутами: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26515159

Comment: а что, нельзя использовать в одних стилях наследование от DarkActionBar а в другой NoActionBar, возможно глупый вопрос, не спорю))

Comment: Дело не в этом - суть проблемы в конфликте `Toolbar` из библиотеки поддержки с `ActionBar` из фреймворка. Нельзя использовать два бара на одном и том же месте.

Answer (score 3):

Это связано с тем, что свойство View объявленое в теме имеет меньший приоритет, чем явное указание свойства View описанные в xml.

Для того чтобы ваша конструкция заработала, вам нужно убрать `android:textColor="#000"` в xml, где объявлена TextView (@+id/tv_from).

---

Можно сделать другим способом:
activity_main.xml

```
...
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:textColor="?recyclerViewItemTextColor"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
...
```

styles.xml

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="recyclerViewItemTextColor">#FF0000</item>
    </style>


    <style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="recyclerViewItemTextColor">#0000FF</item>
    </style>

    <attr name="recyclerViewItemTextColor"/>
```