# Является ли костылем такая работа с ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-style

У меня в прошлом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/930150/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-item-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B) были сложности при работе со стилями. Суть была в том, что при попытке добавить темную тему в приложении возникло ооочень много ошибок и проблем. С горем пополам в основных активити я сделал эту темную тему, но остались некоторые активити, которые сыпались когда я применял тему. Проблема была в том, что я добавлял стрелочку в верхнем левом краю для возврата на пред. активити. Для того чтобы добавить эту стрелку, нужно получить доступ к тулбару, а у меня его в темной теме нет. И вот что я придумал:

1. Светлая и темные темы:

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
   <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
   <item name="colorControlNormal">#5c626d</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">#5c626d</item>
   </style>
   ```

темная

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/darkColorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/darkColorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/darkColorAccent</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/darkColorAccent</item>
<item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item>
</style>
```

2. В активити где возникают проблемы с ActionBar я добавил это:

   ```
       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar_w"
           android:visibility="gone"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
           android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
   ```

до определенного момента он (тулбар) скрыт.

3. В классе, я сделал проверку на темную тему:

   ```
   if (sp.getBoolean("theme", false)) {
           toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_w);
           toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       }
   ```

и вроде все работает, но хотелось бы услышать мнение по поводу моего способа, потому что со стилями я начал работать совсем недавно и не очень хорошо понимаю что и как делается.

Comment: Костыли это все. Правильно надо создать свой базовый подкласс для активити, который знает что тема, как с ней жить и умеет все делать с или без ActionBar. Всем остальным наследоваться от нее.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, а можете более подробно, а то не очень понятно что вы имеете в виду. Если отдельные слова читать, то все понятно, а если в комплексе то не понятно что делать и как исправить ситуацию)

Comment: я бы порекомендовал сделать смену темы с помощью Theme.AppCompat.DayNight как описано здесь (можно делать и автоматическую смену темы и принудительную) http://www.fandroid.info/daynight-nastraivaem-avtomaticheskuyu-smenu-temy-v-android-v-zavisimosti-ot-vremeni-sutok/

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут [в этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/876082/281715) я как то писал про то как устанавливать тему. У себя в Base Activity я создал метод, который возвращает `true/false` примерно так:

```
 public boolean nightModeCheck() {
    boolean nightTheme = false;
    if (themeName.equals(MyConst.DARK_THEME)) {
        nightTheme = true;
    }return nightTheme;
}
```

и теперь , когда мне надо достучаться что бы понять какая тема включена - например для установки темного стиля карты, я проверяю вот так:

```
 if (nightModeCheck()){
..
    }
```

Comment: я перешел по вашей ссылке, но не очень понял где именно у вас применяется вложенный класс, на текущий момент у меня тема пишется в sharedPreferences и дальше оттуда тащится переменная отвечающая за тему, и дальше  применяются стили, под моим вопросом в коментах мне сказали что я все делаю криво, но пока не оч понятно как исправить текущую ситуацию.

Comment: Базовый подкласс - это некая Base Activity от которой наследуются все остальные ваши Activity. Теперь вам не нужно ставить тему везде в каждой Activity, достаточно унаследоваться от этой базовой. И , собственно, когда вам нужно узнать тему вы делаете там проверку и берете значение true/false. Например для включения ночных карт или для других нужд.